# Простой бэкенд с простой базой данных

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть такой кусок кода в html:

```html
<div id="coversgallery">
<div id="cover"><a href="https://hypeddit.com/*ключ3*" target="_blank"><img src="https://hypeddit-gates-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/*ключ3*_coverartmanual"></a></div>
<div id="cover"><a href="https://hypeddit.com/*ключ2*" target="_blank"><img src="https://hypeddit-gates-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/*ключ2*_coverartmanual"></a></div>
<div id="cover"><a href="https://hypeddit.com/*ключ1*" target="_blank"><img src="https://hypeddit-gates-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/*ключ1*_coverartmanual"></a></div>
</div>
```

Дабы не вписывать каждый раз новый div, хотелось бы реализовать автоматическую генерацию новых div-ов через бэкенд. При создании новой записи в БД автоматически создаётся новый div. И при написании в эту запись того самого ключа (любое слово), чтобы он подставлялся в заданные места генерируемого div-а

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewHTML($query) {
  foreach ($query as $arr) {
    echo '<div id="cover"><a href="https://hypeddit.com/'.$arr['key'].'" target="_blank"><img src="https://hypeddit-gates-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$arr['key'].'_coverartmanual"></a></div>';
  }
}
```

Но я бы вам порекомендовал использовать что-то вроде https://twig.symfony.com/

// UPD...

```
<?php
$keyList = Array();

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basename', 'user', 'pass');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT `key` FROM `tablename`') as $row) {
      $keyList[] = $row['key']
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

?>
<div id="coversgallery">
<?php 
foreach($keyList as $val) {
  echo '<div id="cover"><a href="https://hypeddit.com/'.$val.'" target="_blank"><img src="https://hypeddit-gates-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$val.'_coverartmanual"></a></div>';
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: А как бд подключить к данной функции?

Comment: Отредактировал ответ)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь